# what's Taxed line items in the ubercart tax module?

Tags: ubercart

does anyone know what is referring to the fields :
Taxed line items : Shipping,Empty line,Tax in the tax configuration?
i couldn't find an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line items are the items in an order. They can include products, shipping, and tax. The taxed line items are the line items you apply the tax rate to. Generally that would just be the products.